# How to access the users roles in a easy way, using REST api?

Tags: rest, roles

I am trying to obtain user roles to pass from Sharepoint server to a specific tool, and I have to perform a lot of gets to obtain it.

There is a simples REST request to do it?

Comment: Is the information given to you from the REST URL "/_api/web/CurrentUser/Groups" sufficient?

Comment: It should list all user SP Groups, but not FBA roles or AD groups

Answer (score 2):

You could consider the following solution to get permission levels/roles:

- get the effective permissions that the specified user  using `/_api/web/getusereffectivepermissions` endpoint
- determine user roles using [SP.BasePermissions.has(perm) Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee659513%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

**JavaScript example**

```
function getUserEffectivePermissions(webUrl,accountName) 
{
    var endpointUrl = webUrl +  "/_api/web/getusereffectivepermissions(@u)?@u='" + encodeURIComponent(accountName) + "'";
    return $.getJSON(endpointUrl);
}

function getUserRoles(webUrl,accountName)
{
    return getUserEffectivePermissions(webUrl,accountName).then(function(data){
        var permissions = new SP.BasePermissions();
        permissions.initPropertiesFromJson(data);
        var permLevels = [];
        for(var permLevelName in SP.PermissionKind.prototype) {
            if (SP.PermissionKind.hasOwnProperty(permLevelName)) {
               var permLevel = SP.PermissionKind.parse(permLevelName);
               if(permissions.has(permLevel)){
                  permLevels.push(permLevelName);
                }
            }     
        }
        return permLevels;
    });   
}
```

**Usage**

```
var webUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
getUserRoles(webUrl,'i:0#.f|membership|username@tenant.onmicrosoft.com').done(function(permLevels){
    console.log(permLevels); 
});
```